# Complexity of minimizing monotone arithmetical formulas

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, approximation-algorithms, heuristics

Let's say that I have a multi-variate arithmetical expression $A(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ that uses addition and multiplication operations and is also in a very simple form of sums of products, e.g., $A_1(x_1, x_2) = x_1\cdot x_1 + x_1\cdot x_2$.

Let's also say that the size of an expression is the number of addition/multiplication operators that appear in that expression. For example, size of $A_1(x_1, x_2)$ is three.

Now, I want to find another expression (also only using addition and/or multiplication) that is equivalent to the given expression $A$ and is of the minimum size. For example, formula $A_2(x_1, x_2) = x_1\cdot(x_1+x_2)$ of size two would be the answer to input $A_1$.

My question is about the complexity of finding $A_2$ from $A_1$. The decision version of this problem (does there exist such $A_2$ of size at most $k$) is obviously in NP but is it NP-complete?

If yes, then do we have any good approximation algorithm for it? Or other heuristic algorithms?

If not, what is the best known algorithm to solve it?

Comment: seems to be nearly the same as MCSP, minimum circuit size problem (with restricted gates), see eg [rjlipton](https://rjlipton.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/news-on-intermediate-problems/). also close to arithmetic circuit complexity theory. also similar to [polynomial identity testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz%E2%80%93Zippel_lemma).